# Make scrollable div auto resize height to parent div within bootstrap card row col

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, flexbox, bootstrap-grid

I have a problem that i've nearly cracked but could do with some help completing the mission. I'm creating a website using bootstrap on a single page that uses the grid layout with a fixed card height that holds the content.

I've pretty much completed everything else however i'm now making sure the page is responsive at all breakpoints (using bootstraps recommended breakpoint sizes). I've managed to use the d-flex / display: flex features however i've one problem left.

1. I can't get the inner_remaining scroll div col to sit inside the parent div row on either small or medium breakpoints.

I have achieved the task of getting the scroll div col to sit inside the parent div but not in the context of bootstraps row, col, grid. If someone could point me in the right direction that would be useful.

I've also looked at the W3 website for flex box but still can't seem to get it to work, and i need to keep the responsive nature so on medium breakpoint the divs sit in a row and on small breakpoint then sit in a column. The right hand side inner_remaining div will display dynamically generated content of variable sizes hence it needs to scroll and be auto responsive. My code below....

```
<div class="container body-content justify-content-center">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-sm-12">

            <div class="card" style="color: black;height: 400px">
                <div class="card-body">

                    <div class="row" id="outer">
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" id="inner_fixed">

                            I am fixed height<br />
                            I am fixed height<br />
                            I am fixed height<br />

                        </div>
                        <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6" id="inner_remaining">

                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />
                                I take up the remaining height<br />

                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS Breakpoints

Small

```
    #outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
    /*height: 100%;*/
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
}

#inner_remaining {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    flex-grow: inherit;
    flex-shrink: inherit;
    flex-basis: auto;
    margin: auto;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    /*flex: 1 1 1;*/
    /*min-height: 0;*/
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
}
```

Medium

```
    #outer {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row;
    height: 100%;
    /*flex-direction: row;*/
}

#inner_remaining {
    background-color: #DDDDDD;
    flex-grow: 1;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    flex: 1 1 0;
    min-height: 0;
    /*flex-direction: column;*/
}
```

Main

```
#inner_fixed {
height: 100px;
background-color: grey;
```

}

[image]

[image]

Comment: did you try `flex-flow: column nowrap`?

Comment: Hi Matan, just tried that and still hasn't changed the outcome. I'm wondering whether it's to do with the bootstrap row and col interferring because i can produce the result i want just not within the bootstrap grid system.